# Css for text in a container continue on new line and have the container expand downward i necessary?

Tags: css, html

Looking for a way to have text in a container continue on new line and have the container expand downward i necessary?

**Update**

```
 <div class="modal hide fade" id="modalRemoveReserve" style="display:none;">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <div style="border-bottom:1px solid #aaa;"></div>
        <br />
        <div id="reservesTextContainer">

           Text here... lkjasflj fljas fsaj flsjfkd skl

        </div>
        </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">       
    </div>
</div>    

#reservesTextContainer {
        width: 150px;
        height: auto;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't that normal, unless your div is inheriting the height from the div it is contained within.

If you want a container to have a fixed width but have the height of the container vary with the amount of text within it you can do something simple as:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    Some text here
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width:100px;
}
```

See the jfiddle here (you can add as much text as you want and the container will get bigger):http://jsfiddle.net/vagish/Ve7Mj/

If your container is within a div which has a fixed height then you may have issues. You'd have to make that container have a varied height. Making the height vary can be down by the CSS `height:auto;`.

Also you could just make the text within that container overflow by doing the following with the CSS (not really recommended).

```
.container {
    overflow:visible;
}
```

**Based on Updated Code in Question**

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vagish/r7ybg/1/) of updated code show that it works. I've also added this CSS functions:

```
.modal-header {
    height:auto;   
}

#modalRemoveReserve {
    height:auto;   
}
```

Although they may have undesirable effects if a fixed height has already been set.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason this do not work for me. Could it be that my div inheriting some behavior from a parent. Do you know if there is a way to prevent for example a div from inheriting?

Comment: If you could show some code, it would help. One way would be to fix the div height. There are different [height properties](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_height.asp) that can be used.

Comment: Thanks, I have uppdated the question with some code.

Comment: @david2342 Do you have the CSS for the class `.modal-header', '.modal'? Also you say it uses bootstrap, which you mentioned only now. This means it could also be affected by bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to look at [`word-wrap:break-word;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap) combined with ensuring the parent element has `height:auto`

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L5wEz/)

> The word-wrap CSS property is used to specify whether or not the
>   browser may break lines within words in order to prevent overflow (in
>   other words, force wrapping) when an otherwise unbreakable string is
>   too long to fit in its containing box.

Comment: Thanks, but still wont work. The text is expanding outside of the div to the right. The div is inside a Twitter bootstrap modal.

Comment: I have uppdated the question.